# DRYing up template code in Meteor?

Tags: templates, meteor

I'm noticing significant code duplication while building my first Meteor project, and I'm wondering if there's a way to DRY it up.

My database model has stores, each of which have a number of products, and a field with the amount currently in inventory.

```
var store_id = Store.insert({name: 'Store 1', max_items: 50});
var p1 = Product.insert({name: 'General', store_id: store_id, item_count: 20});
var p2 = Product.insert({name: 'Special', store_id: store_id, item_count: 10});
```

I have a template to display a store, and statistics on how many products and items it has.

```
<template name="store">
  <div class="store">
    <b>{{name}}</b>
    <p>Current items: {{current_items}}</p>
    <p>Maximum # of items allowed in inventory: {{max_items}}</p>
    <p>% Full: {{percent_full}}%</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Calculating the number of current items seems fairly straightforward, I pull all the products, sum the item counts (using d3), return the result.

```
Template.store.current_items = function () {
  var store_id = this._id;
  var items = Product.find({store_id: store_id}).fetch();
  if ( items.length > 0 ) {
    var item_cnt = d3.sum(_.pluck(items, 'item_count'));
    return item_cnt;
  }
  else {
    return 'N/A';
  }
};
```

To calculate a percentage comparing the total # of allowed items, and the current items, it seems like I have to reduplicate everything.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
Template.store.percent_full = function () {
  var store_id = this._id;
  var items = Product.find({store_id: store_id}).fetch();
  if ( items.length > 0 ) {
    var item_cnt = d3.sum(_.pluck(items, 'item_count'));
    return item_cnt / max_items * 100;
  }
  else {
    return 'N/A';
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't know meteor, does `{{current_items / max_items * 100}}` in place of `{{percent_full}}` do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the duplicated logic to a separate function and just call it appropriately from different helpers. This is not really different from DRYing any other JS code.

Comment: What about the Product.find call?  Is there a way to avoid having to do this twice, once to calculate the count of items, again to calculate percentage?  Memoization isn't really an option since product counts can change and should update reactively.

Comment: Well, you can create a reactive Deps.autorun manually outside of helpers, calculate the sum into sum reactive var (or just Session to be simple) and then depend on that value in your helpers

Comment: Are you using Iron-Router for the project?  If so, it would likely make much more sense to put the Product.find call in the data section of your route.

Comment: Between the two approaches (Deps.autorun, Iron Router), is there a "right" place to put this?  My newb opinion leans towards Deps.autorun, since it needs to be recalculated when new items are added to a collection, and I assume the router is invoked client side?  On the other hand polluting session with a million intermediate values doesn't seem great.

Comment: I don't think recalculating this particular thing twice is gonna hurt any time soon. Don't optimize prematurely.